# Plugin "Sonar PDF Report Plugin" compatible with SQ 5.6?

Tags: sonarqube

We're looking for a SQ plugin that would allow us to generate a PDF report witha a list of issues from the analyzed project.

There is this community plugin https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pdf-report but as far as I know it's deprecated. Can you confirm that?

Is there any other option to achieve the goal?

We're currently using SQ version 5.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that plugin is deprecated: have a look at the [deprecated plugins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Deprecated+Plugins) and the [plugin version matrix](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix) pages. You can have a look at the [Governance plugin](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/enterprise/) but than you have to pay for an enterprise version. The best "free" option is to use the [Web API](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Documentation) to get the information you need and generate a PDF report yourself.